# Spring web run after startup

Tags: spring, startup

I run a `spring` web application (not `spring boot`).
On startup the application requests a dataset from another server. This dataset takes about a minute to be processed. When I deploy this application to the tomcat, it takes a minute. The website itself will not be available until the dataset request has been processed completely. But actually I would like to see, that users are already able to login and the dataset is processed without stopping the rest of the application from working.

Currently I have a service class and use the `@PostConstruct`-Annotation.

```
@Service
public class StartupService {
  @PostConstruct
  public void load() {
    //perform the dataset request
    ...
  }
}
```

I found similar article here on stackoverflow, that suggested trying the ApplicationListener. But this has the same effect. HTTP Requests to the website are not answered unless the dataset request has finished.

```
@Service
public class StartupService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    //perform the dataset request
    ...
  }
}
```

Of course it would be possible, to start a new `Thread`, but I would like to know, what the best approach for this problem would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) doc:

> ... This method MUST be invoked before the class is put into service...

So Spring cannot service a request until the @PostContruct method finishes.

As you suggested, start a new thread manually, or:

- from the @PostConstruct method, call a public method in another bean annotated with  @Async and Spring will asynchronously invoke the method which will allow the @PostConstruct method to finish immediately and start servicing requests
- from the @PostConstruct method, @Schedule a one time task - for example 1 minute from now

See also: @EnableAsync and/or @EnableScheduling

Comment: thanks for your response. i have several controller or service classes. My problem is that none of those works, until the StartupService finished the @PostConstruct method. From the documentation it says, "the class is put into service", not "any class is put into service". The StartupService itself does not provide any service besides the startup routine. I will check the '''@Async'''' option now.